# mySQL Subselect with multiple results should be shown in 1 field

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I want to have shown multiple results in 1 fields for a subselect.

As example:

```
table 1:
tbl1_ID, fistname, familyname

table 2:
tbl2_ID, carbrand

table 3 is the n:n relationship for table 1 and 2
tbl1, tbl2
```

The Person of table 1 should be able to own several cars (for example Ford and BMW).
The car brand of table 2 is applicable to several People of course.

I want to have listed the cars of each Person in 1 data field

Example:

```
Mueller  | Hans   | Ford,BMW

Jaeger   | Erwin  | BMW,Mercedes,Jaguar

Fritsche | Sascha | Mercedes
```

How to do this? I cannot do with subselect because it allows only 1 result.
Also, it doesn't work with LEFT JOIN because I want to have shown each Person once only.

Thanks! MR

Comment: Hint: `group_concat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use group_concat and you should use inner join between the two related  tables based  on table 3 and group by

```
select a.familyname, a.fistname,  group_concat(b.carbrand)
from  table_3 c
inner join table1 a on c.table1_id = a.table1_id 
inner join table2 b on c.table2_id = b.table2_id 
group by a.familyname, a.fistname
```